# Pypy: Why does a "simpler" nested list take longer to flatten?

Tags: recursion, pypy, flatten

I had the need to flatten some nested lists. After writing the flatten function, I naturally tried to see how many ways I could break it. I finally ran it through pypy and was delighted to discover that when the lists got really deep pypy was running significantly faster than cpython.

However, I'm seeing a strange situation where a test with a larger, more complicated list, with a larger variety of elements is actually executing faster than the "simpler" list.

Test 1, which has fewer elements, is consistently about a second slower to run (using time pypy ./script.py) than test 2.

```
def flatten(lol):
    if not any([isinstance(i, list) for i in lol]):
        return lol

    flatter = [i for i in lol if not isinstance(i, list)]
    for sublist in lol:
        if isinstance(sublist, list):
            flatter.extend(sublist)
    return flatten(flatter)

def silly(l):
    return [l, [l]]

nested_function = [["kaplutis", ["mucus", ["my brain", ["is","filled",["with",["pus",]]]]]], "santa gertrudis",[[[[["innermost",flatten(["in", "func"])]]]]]]

tuples = ["empty tuple retained-->", (), ("2-tuple not flattened",), ("I'm the only thing in this tuple")]

dicts = [{"hip": "hop", "ster": "toad"}]

lone_dict = {"lone": 1, "dict": 2}

silly_list = ["1"]
for i in range(20):
    silly_list = silly(silly_list)

# test 1 - only the absurdly nested list
print(len(flatten(silly_list)))

# test 2 - absurdly nested list, with 
lol = [nested_function, tuples, dicts, lone_dict, silly_list]
print(len(flatten(lol)))
```

The only thing I can figure is I'm running into some accidental optimization when the JIT is  dealing with the simpler nested lists before "silly_list" in the second test.

Comment: Clarification: Tests run with python 2.7.2, python 3.2.2, and pypy 1.9 (binary from pypy-1.9-linux64.tar.bz2), all on ubuntu 12.04 x86_64.

Comment: Also: kindly ignore the goofy values in my test cases, I tend to stick whatever pops into my head into such, and did not consider that they might be a distraction. (No one has complained about this, but looking at it a day later, I see that it might cause one to take the question less seriously). Thanks.

Comment: Further Clarification: The tests should be run separately, first by cominting out "lol = [nested_function, tuples, dicts, lone_dict, silly_list]" and "print(len(flatten(lol)))", then running with /usr/bin/time, then repeating the test after commenting out "print(len(flatten(silly_list)))". This should have been explained in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: don't comment on your own question, [update](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11125957/edit) it instead.

Comment: drop unnecessary `[]` inside `any()`. Run profiler. Run each test in a loop to exclude jit warm-up time. See [Analysing python's performance under PyPy](http://lostinjit.blogspot.com/2011/11/analysing-pythons-performance-under.html)

Answer (score 1):

this particular flatten function did hit various bad perf points in cpython and pypy

we figured it on irc some time ago and the fix was to create a completely different flatten function that was faster in cpython and much faster on pypy

i don't remember the url, it would be nice if OP would provide

the basic code was along the lines of

```
def flatten(items, akk=None)
 if akk is None:
   akk  = []
 for item in items:
   if isinstance(item, list):
     flatten(item, akk)
   else:
     akk.append(item)
```

Comment: This is indeed the code. Sorry for not posting an update. Mea culpa. I plead workload. Thanks kindly for your help!

Answer (score 0):

<sup>an answer instead of a comment to include the code</sup>

It is hard to understand what your code does. Make sure it is correct. Optimize later. You could test the results against:

```
def flatten(lst, nonscalar_types=list):
    for x in lst:
        if isinstance(x, nonscalar_types):
            yield from flatten(x) # pep 380
        else:
            yield x # non-list type
```

#### Example

```
print(sum(1 for _ in flatten(lol)))
```

Comment: The code takes a nested list ("list of lists") and returns all elements in a single list. It works as expected. I'm sure that "Make sure it is correct. Optimize later." is always good advice. I do like the up-to-the-minute use of "field from <expr>" in your example, but it does not run properly with 2.7.2 or pypy 1.9, (    yield from flatten(x) # pep 380
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax). The question remains "why is the larger input running faster in pypy".

Comment: @lysdexia: the above is a comment to your question, not an answer (as explicitly stated in the first line). `yield from f()` can be replaced by `for i in f(): yield i`. For `[[1],2,3]` your code produces `[2,3,1]` instead of `[1,2,3]`